# 200 status code returned from REST in spite of Jackson error

Tags: rest, jersey, jackson

I'm using REST with Jersey, and Jackson for JSON processing. When the client sends a request with invalid JSON (in my case, unrecognized property), Jackson is throwing an exception (my resource code is not executed, it fails before), but the client get status code 200.

Can I do something so the client will get a different status code?

My REST method:

```
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response myMethod(MyClass message)
    {
        try
        {
            //my logic here
            return Response.ok(result).build();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }
```

Here is the exception I get in the log from Jackson:

```
07-11-2013 11:01:06 [com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse] [http-nio-8100-exec-5] [ERROR] - The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Tier" (Class com.somthing.MyClass), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1036e65; line: 2, column: 15] (through reference chain: com.somthing.MyClass["Tier"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:246)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:604)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:590)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:689)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:514)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2376)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1166)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:474)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.bmc.aps.commonserver.rest.resources.filter.RESTHttpFilter.doFilter(RESTHttpFilter.java:56)
    at com.bmc.aps.portal.rest.resources.filter.PortalRESTHttpFilter.doFilter(PortalRESTHttpFilter.java:35)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.bmc.aps.commonserver.logging.RESTLoggingFilter.callDoFilter(RESTLoggingFilter.java:166)
    at com.bmc.aps.commonserver.logging.RESTLoggingFilter.doFilter(RESTLoggingFilter.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Add code for your resource method to the question. Sounds like you are swallowing the JSON exception, leading to a 'success' response.

Comment: I can add my code, but I don't think it will help to something. I'm not 'swallowing' the JSON exception. My code isn't even executed, it fail before getting to my code.

Comment: Odd, you should definitely be getting an HTTP 500 status back and not a 200. Not an answer to your original question, but to eliminate the exception you can add a [`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) to your POJO.

Answer (score 0):

You could "catch" those exceptions and throw a "personalized" "WebApplicationException", with a HTTP code status/error different from the one thrown by that exception.

Here is an example of that type of personalized exception, with a 400 error status (bad request):

```
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class PersonalizedExceptionBadRequest extends WebApplicationException{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Create a HTTP 400 (Bad Request) exception.
     */
    public PersonalizedExceptionBadRequest(){
        super(Response.status(400).build());
    }

    /**
     * Create a HTTP 400 (Bad Request) exception.
     * 
     * @param message
     *            the String that is the entity of the 400 response.
     */
    public PersonalizedExceptionBadRequest(String message){
        super(Response.status(400).entity(message).type("text/plain")
                .build());
    }

}
```

Then you need to "declare" in your API jersey method that it "throws" a "WebApplicationException".

Comment: I tried doing that. I added your class and declared that my methods throw 'PersonalizedExceptionBadRequest', but it doesn't work.

Comment: What did not work? What error did it give to you? Try to declare that the API method throws a "WebApplicationException" instead, to see if it returns the same problem.

Comment: It didn't worked meaning I still get 200 response. here's my method signature:  public Response myMethod(MyMessage message) throws PersonalizedExceptionBadRequest

Comment: but are you "catching" the exception you report in the original question (UnrecognizedPropertyException) before you throw this new exception?

Comment: I can't catch it because it is not thrown from my code. If I'm trying to add catch clause for "UnrecognizedPropertyException" I'm getting compilation error - "error: exception UnrecognizedPropertyException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement"

Comment: This is not the focus of the question, but you are sending an element in the JSON that is "invalid" (Unrecognized)... tackling that probably solves your problem... but that will not answer the question you have about the return of a "200" status code. Not sure why Jersey responds with such a status code.

Comment: well, I'm not the one sending the malformed JSON :) But I don't want my API to return 200 when I get such JSON.